# Adding extra information to a subtotal row by linking to another spreadsheet in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

My task is to add another column to a backlog and link data from another worksheet to the backlog. The data should be linked to the corresponding subtotal row in the backlog by inputting the data to a new column in the backlog.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to link the cells without going one-by-one.  Each time I've tried I've come into issues that have to do with data hiding. Since I have to do this with large amounts of information, I don't have the time to do this work one-by-one.  Is there any time-efficient solution for this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the vlookup function?

Comment: Yes, there are time-efficient solutions for this-but it would be very helpful for you to add some sample data to help us better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In 'new column' first subtotal row, lookup the value of what you want from the row immediately above. Filter on subtotals and copy down the new formula.